# Wont produce the expected output Truthtable in java using stack

Tags: java, stack

This is my code:
import java.util.*;

public class TruthTable {

```
public static boolean evaluateExpression(String expression, boolean p, boolean q) {
    Stack<Boolean> stack = new Stack<>();
    Stack<Character> opStack = new Stack<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < expression.length(); i++) {
        char c = expression.charAt(i);
        if (c == 'p') {
            stack.push(p);
        } else if (c == 'q') {
            stack.push(q);
        } else if (c == '¬') {
            boolean b = stack.pop();
            stack.push(!b);
        } else if (c == '∧') {
            // Check if the next character is a ¬ character.
            if (i + 1 < expression.length() && expression.charAt(i + 1) == '¬') {
                // If the next character is a ¬ character, pop the top of the stack and negate it,
                // then push the conjunction of the negated value and the value of q.
                boolean b = stack.pop();
                stack.push(!(b && q));
                // Increment the index to skip the ¬ character.
                i++;
            } else {
                // If the next character is not a ¬ character, simply push the conjunction of the
                // value of p and the value of q.
                stack.push(stack.pop() && q);
            }
        } else if (c == '∨' || c == '→' || c == '↔' || c == '⊕' || c == '⊼' || c == '⊽') {
            while (!opStack.isEmpty() && getPrecedence(c) <= getPrecedence(opStack.peek())) {
                char op = opStack.pop();
                applyOperator(op, stack);
            }
            opStack.push(c);
        }
    }

    while (!opStack.isEmpty()) {
        char op = opStack.pop();
        applyOperator(op, stack);
    }

    return stack.pop();
}

private static void applyOperator(char op, Stack<Boolean> stack) {
    boolean b1 = stack.pop();
    boolean b2 = stack.pop();
    switch (op) {
        case '∧':
            stack.push(b1 && b2);
            break;
        case '∨':
            stack.push(b1 || b2);
            break;
        case '→':
            stack.push(!b1 || b2);
            break;
        case '↔':
            stack.push(b1 == b2);
            break;
        case '⊕':
            stack.push(b1 != b2);
            break;
        case '⊼':
            stack.push((b1 && b2) || (!b1 && b2) || (b1 && !b2));
            break;
        case '⊽':
            stack.push(b1 && b2 && stack.pop());
            break;
        case '¬':
            stack.push(!b1);
            break;
    }
}

private static int getPrecedence(char op) {
    switch (op) {
        case '¬':
            return 3;
        case '∧':
            return 2;
        case '∨':
            return 1;
        case '→':
            return 0;
        case '↔':
            return 0;
        case '⊕':
            return 1;
        case '⊼':
            if (op == '∨' || op == '→' || op == '↔' || op == '⊕') {
                return 2;
            } else {
                return 3;
            }
        case '⊽':
            return 2;
        default:
            return -1;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String expression = "pq¬∨pq∧→";
    System.out.println("p\tq\t(" + expression + ")");
    for (boolean p : new boolean[]{true, false}) {
        for (boolean q : new boolean[]{true, false}) {
            System.out.println(p + "\t" + q + "\t" + evaluateExpression(expression, p, q));
        }
    }
}
```

}

The expected result is true false true false but it prints out false true false true and ive been trying to figure out how to fix it but I just cant. Will appreciate any help

Ive tried changing the precedence but it only produced the output True true true true

Answer (score 0):

I don't expect many people will be able to help you, especially if you cannot see the logic error and you are the author!

When writing code like this, your best option is to write **Unit Tests**.  Test parts of the implementation first and then give your algorithm expressions bit by bit and work up to more complex cases.

Note that your use of `private static` methods may frustrate your ability to test parts or mock out parts of the code.  Go find an article about Unit Testing and Dependency Injection; it will be worthwhile your investment.